# How do I remove the lrm character from query results using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, utf

How do I remove the lrm character (U+200E) from query results using MySQL?

Comment: Can you give an example of some text for which you want to remove the left-to-right mark, and what do you want the text to look like after removing this character?

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate a leading LRM character, you can run the following:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field`=SUBSTRING(`field`,2) WHERE HEX(`field`) LIKE 'E2808E%';
```